# Find the algebraic form of this number. In response, write down the real part.

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex number has a length of 7.07 and an angle of -45 degrees. Find the algebraic form of this number. In response, write down the real part.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: You just copied and pasted a question, please put some more effort into formulating your thoughts about it